# Laravel - how to serve a new laravel project to browser

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, laravel-5

This is the first time I've used a PHP framework.

I've been following the Laravel documentation to install Composer and Laravel, and everything seems to have gone smoothly.

But now I've finished the installation/configure instructions, and I have created a project, I can't see any instructions on how to serve my application so it's viewable via a browser?

I have used Ruby on Rails before, which came with an easy way to get an instance of the application running via a built-in web server.

Is there something similar with Laravel, or do I need to somehow configure my standard Apache instance to serve the application?

I'm guessing there is something I've overlooked or misunderstood in the documentation.

Comment: Homestead is my prefered webserver voor Larevel. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead A standard dev stack like MAMP or WAMP should do fine though. Or you could go for the built in `php artisan serve` command

Comment: `LAMP` in case of `Linux distro` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, you can do it by using following in your terminal.

open your terminal, and navigate to directory where you have your project `abc`

and fire following command

```
php artisan serve
```

[image]

Now you can access it in browser by going to `http://localhost:8000`

hope you get it

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add to the answer of Mubin Khalid . You can choose your own port number like

php artisan serve --port=8080

This is helpful when running two or more project.

Answer (score -3):

You can also serve with you ip address

```html
php artisan serve --host=ip_of_computer_running_laravel --port=8080
```

works to access server with in same network.

if you are accessing from same laptop you can just browse to ip_of_computer_running_laravel:8080 but if you are browsing from other computer in the network ip_of_computer_running_laravel:8080